# WordPress add_image_size not working. Images uploaded after thumbnail size is defined

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have looked around here and other forums for a solution of my problem. Almost everywhere the solution is to install Regenerate Thumbnail plugin, because images uploaded before thumbnail size is defined will not work.

For me, the issue is all my images were uploaded after I defined the thumbnail size: `add_image_size('home_grid_thumbnail', 200, 150, true);` But they are rendering with `1px * 1px` dimensions.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried to locate one of the home_grid_thumbnail images on the server, to see if they are saved in the correct dimensions?

Comment: Will those be saved in the same location i.e. `wp_upload_dir` ? Source shows this: `<img width="1" height="1" src="http://album.multibaselocal.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/52288189.jpg" class="attachment-home_grid_thumbnail size-home_grid_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" />`. I am developing in my local. I thought the resizing / cropping happens run time using some core API. I may be wrong. Does WP save a separate copy of each image being uploaded? In the source I can see the location of the thumbnail image is the same as where the images were actually uploaded.

Comment: they should be in your uploads folder together with the original image - called the original-file-name-NumberxNumber, where the numbers will represent the dimensions of the file size created.

Comment: In that case I don't see any generated thumbnail. I am using AJAX upload. Can this be an issue? And by the way, if there is a separate image uploaded, why `<img src />` is using the original file name? Shouldn't it use the thumbnail image name? In my case image won't be found, that is understandable. But why the original file name is being referred?

Comment: Are you on a local host?

Comment: If so: sounds like you don't have an image library enabled with PHP (that probably should have generated some errors so maybe first look at your php error logs). Check if GD2 is enabled in your php.ini file.

Comment: Ok. I have realized that thumbnails are not at being generated at the time of uploading images via AJAX from front end. Because when I upload from admin, the thumbnails are generated. So I must be doing something wrong or my settings needs to be rechecked! Thank you @Stender for driving me to the right path. I would look more into it :)

Comment: Awesome, sorry i couldn't be of more help, glad that you found something.

Comment: Actually you had been a great help! You showed me the way... :)

Comment: @Stender. Finally done! I missed this bit: `include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );`. Your advice put me in the right direction. Thank you once again for helping me out :) Can you please create an answer with your comment so that I can up-vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the discussions/comments OP found out that he needed /image.php to be included.

Normally these files need to be included as dependencies when handling images on the frontend

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
```

This does not need to be included/required when building a plugin etc for the control panel, since the functions in them are already loaded when in the admin section